# How to get version of python dependencies/modules, including external applications called via subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, linux, version-control, dependencies

I have a set of python scripts that I run frequently on different machines that depend on a few external libraries as well as some other applications spawned via `subprocess.Popen`.

As expected depending on the version of the installed modules and applications the output varies. To address this I would like to keep track of which versions were in use at runtime.

In order to do this I've considered the following steps:

1. Using [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html) to collect dependencies.
2. Try to call `module.__version__`, `module.get_version()` or other common
   ways to store version information on each collected module.
3. Collect all calls to `subprocess.Popen` and try to get a version number by parsing the output with different arguments such as -version, -v, -?, -h, ...

Steps 2 and 3 could be greatly improved by the use of distribution specific ([Debian](http://www.debian.org) in my case) tools such as [dpkg](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkgtools.en.html) to get versions of installed packages. The downside is that it becomes not only OS but also distribution specific, however I do realize that the initial approach is extremely inefficient and error-prone, if functional at all.

So my question is if there is any package out there to address this or if anyone has a better suggestion on how to implement it?

Comment: I think you are on the right track there. Remember that the environment, especially $PATH and PYTHONPATH, but some others too, have a huge effect on what is found. So if you are running your analyzer separate from your script, it needs to be run with the same environment. This is especially important if your script is spawned from a daemon such as a webserver or cron, as those environments usually are very different from a login shell environ.

Comment: The script should be run on the style of modulefinder. Probably with a ./launch script.py approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two years passed and some new tools came into play.

To take care of point 1 and 2 there is now `pip freeze` specially when coupled with `virtualenv`.

For external applications I had to resource to the package manager (apt-file, dpkg, qlist, emerge,... depending on the system) on the system which included all the expected pitfalls.

I would still like to make a reference to Ross' answer as it produced the desired result. The disadvantage (from my point of view) is that it collected a lot more dependencies than strictly required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly investigating your dependencies in python, and if you are running in Linux/Unix, you can wrapper your program with `memoize.py`.  `memoize.py` uses `strace`, or "system trace", to watch all system read and write commands that your program generates and then stores these dependencies to a file.  `memoize.py` may also be use as a library, so you can use its functions internally within your program and get the dependencies in a python data structure.

Comment: I'm currently looking into it. I'm not entirely sure if memoize won't give me more than I want and then make it yet more complicated... I will get back in touch if I get to a decent point. Thanks for the tip.